# antiderivative of $8t^{-{1/2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to find the antiderivative of $8t^{-{1/2}}$ but im just not understanding how to do this.

I saw someone get out of $t^{1/2}$ the answer $2t^{1/2}$ Can someone help me out?

Comment: Informal: Let's try $x^{1/2}$. Check by differentiating. Too bad, derivative is $(1/2)x^{-1/2}$, and we want $8x^{-1/2}$. Easy fix: Multiply by $16$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas What's informal about that?

Comment: @DavidMitra: he's not wearing a tux.

Comment: Well, it is formally correct. And it is a useful strategy, I like to throw away constants and recover them at the end. It is also a useful approach to $xe^x$ say. Guess antiderivative is $xe^x$, check by differentiation, oops, but easy fix.

Answer (score 3):

Don't be worried about a negative exponent that's *not* $-1$: you apply the same rules as you would when integrating, say, $\displaystyle\;\int 8t^3 dt,\;$ for example.

Those rules, recall, are:

For any $n\neq -1$ and any number $b$, $$\int b\cdot x^n dx \quad = \quad b\int x^n dx \quad =\quad b\cdot \frac{1}{(n + 1)} x^{(n+1)} + C \quad \text{(where $C$ is a constant)}.$$

$$\text{So, since}\;\;(-1/2) \neq -1, \quad \int 8t^{-1/2} dt = \frac{8}{\left(\frac12\right)} t^{\,(-\frac12)\, +\, 1)} + C \quad = \;\dots \;?$$

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{8}{\frac12} = \dfrac22\cdot \dfrac{8}{\frac12} = 16$. And $t^{(-1/2) + 1} = t^{1/2} = \sqrt{t}$. That gives you $16t^{1/2} + C = 16\sqrt{t} + C$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\int x^\alpha dx = \frac{1}{\alpha + 1} x^{\alpha + 1} + C$, as long as $\alpha \neq -1$. Also, note that $\int 8 t^{-\frac{1}{2}} dt = 8 \int t^{-\frac{1}{2}} dt$.