# antiderivative of $\frac{4}{\sqrt{u}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to get the antiderivative of $\frac{4}{\sqrt{u}}$

Im not sure how to apply antiderivative rules when having a question like this?

Comment: That'd be better if you specify with respect to what eventually you want to integrate.

Comment: @soniccool: You [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257535/antiderivative-of-8t-1-2) covers _almost exactly_ the same material.  Why don't you spend some time thinking about the answeres given there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Rewrite $\sqrt{u}$ as $u^{1/2}$. Thus, $\frac{4}{\sqrt{u}} = 4u^{-1/2}$.

Recall that $\int x^n \ dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ for all $n \ne -1$.

Then,
$$4\int u^{-1/2} \ du = 4 \cdot \frac{u^{-1/2 + 1}}{1/2} = 8u^{1/2} + C = 8\sqrt{u} + C$$

Comment: Yea this is where im stuck i dont know how to continue now with fractions and the u and what not?

Comment: I filled in some more details. Let me know if you something does not make sense.

Comment: tHAT FORUMULA HELPED! Awesome now i understandit actually

Comment: Glad to hear it! Note that the formula only holds for polynomials of the form $x^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can re-write this as $4 u^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. Now, use the rule for integrating functions of the form $\int u^n du$. I'll give more details if you need.

Answer (score 0):

The antiderivative of $\frac{4}{\sqrt u}=4u^{-1/2}$ is $4\cdot \frac{1}{1/2}u^{-1/2+1}+C=8u^{1/2}+C$

If you are just looking for an answer (and not an explanation), try [this](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=sqrt%28%28a%5E2%2bx%29/x%29&random=false). On the other hand, if you're looking to understand, please make sure you understand each step and comment below if you need further clarification.

Comment: I dont get how we get 8 out of that?

Comment: Look at @Brett Frankel's calculation and see that $4/(1/2)=8.$

Comment: @soniccool Try differentiating the antiderivative and see if that helps you see what happens to the constants out front.